# Produce a Dynkin system from a finite set of finite sets

Tags: algorithms, reference-request

[Updated question]

A [Dynkin System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) is, provided all sets are finite, a collection of subsets of a universal set closed under complements with the universal set and closed under union of disjoint sets.

In particular, every Dynkin system contains the universal set and the empty set.

Fix a finite set $\Omega$ and let $\mathcal E$ be any set of subsets of $\Omega$.  Let $\delta(\mathcal E)$ be the Dynkin system generated by $\mathcal E$.  This is the intersection of all Dynkin systems on $\Omega$ that contain $\mathcal E$.

The sets in the Dynkin system $\delta(\mathcal E)$ are partially ordered by inclusion.  Its minimal element is the empty set and its maximal element is $\Omega$.

**Question**: Is there an efficient algorithm to determine the atoms of $\delta(\mathcal E)$, that is, the elements which contain no other set of $\delta(\mathcal E)$ except the empty set?

Note that this set may be much smaller than the full Dynkin system.  For example, the Dynkin system generated by $n$ distinct elements is the Boolean algebra of cardinality $2^n$.  See below for a further example.

In the previous formulation, kept below for reference, I did not assume that the universal set is in $\mathcal E$.  Therefore, the resulting set is not a Dynkin system.  However, for my application, I can in fact assume that the universal set is in $\mathcal E$.

[Original question]

A [Sperner family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner_family) is a family $\mathcal F$ of subsets of a finite set in which none of the sets contains another.

Suppose that $\mathcal E$ is any finite set of finite sets.  For any two elements $A$ and $B$ of $\mathcal E$ such that $A\subsetneq B$, add $B\setminus A$ to $\mathcal E$. Repeat this process until no new elements are added. Then return the minimal elements of $\mathcal E$ with respect to inclusion (which is a Sperner family).

**Question**: is there an efficient algorithm to obtain this set?
Does this procedure have a name?

My first idea was to proceed as follows:

- create the poset whose elements are the sets in $\mathcal E$, ordered by containment
- while there is a covering relation $A\subset B$, delete $B$ from the poset, and add $B\setminus A$.

I implicitly assumed that it would not matter which relation is chosen.  Unfortunately, this is wrong. A colleague found the following counterexample:
$$
\mathcal E = \{\{1,2,3,4\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,4\}\}
$$
The desired output is
$$
\{\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,4\}, \{1,4\}\}.
$$

Following the (incorrect) algorithm above, choosing the relation $\{1,2\}\subset\{1,2,3,4\}$ first, we only obtain
$$
\{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{1,4\}\}.
$$

Comment: It is also possible to create an $O(n+d)$ algorithm, where $d$ is the number of elements from $\mathcal{E}$ that have a common intersection.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami: what I am currently doing is to create the poset, collect all the covering relations of the minimal elements, replace those, and repeat until there are no relations left.  Possibly this is good enough.  Its complexity is unclear to me, because it may happen that a replacement creates more relations, but I admit that it doesn't look so bad experimentally.

Comment: @nirshahar: could you please expand?

Comment: @MartinRubey Your algorithm always converges since the size of a set is always decreasing. If there are $n$ sets in $\mathcal{E}$, and the ground set has $m$ elements, then the running time of your algorithm is $O(mn) $ X time to find sets $A \subset B$ in $\mathcal{E}$. But this algorithm is inefficient.

Comment: Thinking back at this, there also needs to be a factor of the amount of values in $\cup\mathcal{E}$ (the union of all sets in $\mathcal{E}$). The simple solution of mapping elements from $\cup\mathcal{E}$ to their respective sets, and applying the operations only between sets that have a common element. This would result in a fairly weird complexity, which we might write as $O(\sum_{x\in \cup\mathcal{E}} d^2_x)$ where $d_x$ is the number of sets that contain $x$. So please disregard my previous comment about a solution in $O(n+d)$ since it doesn't take into account such factors.

Comment: Maybe I missing something, but for a Dykin system isn't the minimal elements always the empty set? Do you mean minimal besides the empty set? 

Suppose $S$ in the system, then $S^c$ is in the system, then $S \cup S^c$ is in the system, and finally $(S \cup S^c)^c = \emptyset$ is in the system.

Comment: Yes, I meant the atoms, the elements covering the empty set.

Comment: What is the meaning of "the minimal elements (covering the empty set)"?  Can you explain or define that in different words?  Do you want the algorithm to output all minimal elements?  What is the definition of minimal in this context?  I think I'm most confused by the parenthetical.